# IntelliJ Git Integration - git --version empty output

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am currently trying to use the Git integration for IntelliJ 2016.2, but whenever I point it to the executable I get the following issue:

[image: Git Version output problem]

This doesn't technically prevent the integration from working but it does cause issues updating the index etc.

I'm running Windows 7, with a completely fresh install, but I had the same issue on the previous PC (these are work machines with various irritating levels of security) but I have colleagues with the same kit that have no such issues.

**EDIT**

I should have mentioned that it works fine on the command line:

[image: Git Command Line Output]

I'm sure I've read something about a change in the way this works internally that means when it's called by an outside executable the output gets screwed up, but I can't find the reference again.

Comment: Within the CLI, are you able to run `git --version` and get any output?

Comment: @BrianaSwift Yeah the CLI is fine, see edit.

Comment: I'm not a windows dev so this may be an obvious answer...in your terminal it's looking like you're in root C drive, but in IntelliJ you're looking in a tools directory. Is there any way the default is somewhere else, like `C:\prog\git`?

Comment: The tools directory is on PATH, which is why I can run it from root of C:\

Comment: I'm starting to give up on this being the weirdness of my work environment. Git isn't actually giving me any problems with graphs or commits and pushes, and I haven't seen the popup in a while, might be that a later release happens to have fixed it.

Answer (score 17):

Make sure you set the right path to Git executable: 
IntelliJ > Settings > Version Control > Git should be  C:/.../Git/**bin**/git.exe

Do not set git-bash.exe or git-cmd.exe

Comment: The Git path is correct, I have checked it in the command line. See the first screen grab which shows the path of the Git executable.

Comment: I'm in work and can't access the image.  However "Do not set `git-bash.exe` or `git-cmd.exe`" solved it for me, hence upvote.  I'd hazard a guess you are pointing to one of the above, and NOT `git.exe` though?

Answer (score 9):

Happened to me the exact same thing.

git is working from the command line but the path:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
```

and the path (as the say [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000094860-PyCharm-hangs-on-Identifying-Git-Version-Git-standalone-and-GitHub)):

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

(which is the path I got when I did `where git.exe` in cmd)

didn't work.

So I went to git-bash and did `where git.exe`, and I got a different path, which is working.

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response! I wasn't using Git Bash at the time, but I can see that the mingw64 directory is present in my standard install of Git, so this might be useful to someone who comes across the issue now.

Comment: I was really tired of seeing git configuration error everytime I start IntelliJ. Thank you for this answer. I did use terminal and see it my Git landed into appdata folder. But it works now.

Answer (score 2):

first get your git.exe path by using command. type this in cmd terminal

```
git --info-path
```

then find location `your_directory\Git\bin\git.exe`
mine was `C:\Users\saigopi\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin`

add this path in android studio

**File->Settings-> Version Control -> Git**

add your path at **Path to Git Executable** and test it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried a number of things. It eventually began working again when I downgraded my git install.

- Close Intellij
- Uninstall git (my version was **git version 2.10.1.windows.1**)
- Download an older version from here:
  https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/tags
  I used this specific version:
  https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.8.4.windows.1
- Reload Intellij. Git should now work.