# Attach github in Android studio2.2.3

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

In My android studio 2.2.3 the github option is not available only the Mercurial option is their to use, how do i attach github to android studio and sync or commit my project please anyone help

Comment: Try installing "Git Integration" and "Git Hub" plugins in your Android Studio

Comment: Thanks alot its done :)

Comment: can I make it as answer so that you can accept it?

Comment: ya sure, Can you help me out in one more time now its showing me empty  git version output error, the similar problem is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38867291/intellij-git-integration-git-version-empty-output

Comment: Thanks, and I will try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to install `Git Integration` and `Git Hub` plugins into your Android Studio. Here is the step if you're confused.

1. In your Android Studio, pres `Shitf + Ctrl + A` to show "Action and Option Seacrh" popup.
2. Type "Plugins" and select most top result.
3. Type plugin name that you want to install. If no result is shown, click "Browse"
4. `GitHub` or `Git Integration` plugins should appear by now. Install them
5. Continue your awesome coding.